# Insert A3 pdf page in A4 report

Tags: pdf, paper-size

I have a .pdf file in A3 format that I would like to insert in a report with a normal pagesize of A4. The A3 page should be inserted as orientation="landscape" as in page 103 in the picture below.
Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and `\includepdf{...}` use you must, mmmh! ;-), perhaps `geometry` package as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Neither of those will allow you to change the size of the page mid document.

Comment: @cfr: No, of course not, if the A3 document should survive in its original size.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes. It is not very clear right now. I think the picture is supposed to show it at original size, but maybe that is not entirely intended.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, totally unclear. Let's wait for some reaction (but I fear, there will be none)

Comment: I know how to use includepdf, but I want the pdf to be inserted as an  A3 paper in landscape orientation. ?